# Does the Samsung gear vr trigger work on a command Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, gear-vr

I made cardboard aplication and i use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` on google cadboard it works. But i dont have gear vr device to try on it. I am search on a google and i find that they have bluetooth controller and trigger button on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. GearVR has a external controller and a touchpad to trigger input.
And yes Input.GetMouseButton(0) works in GearVR too provided you have to make some changes.